# Unix EOF character appearing in output of Python script

Tags: python, command-line-interface

I have a few python files that take input as two ints separated by spaces, and return an int. (My class requires this.) I'm having an issue where an extra "D" appears along with my output, after I hit `Ctrl-D` to end the input. It's running the programs correctly, though - the output is correct.

Here's what I'm seeing:

```
$ python gcd_euclid.py 
144 100
4D
$ python pc_1_ucsd.py
3 4
7D
```

Oddly...this wasn't happening yesterday, and I'm not sure if I changed anything. Does anyone have any ideas why this is happening and how to fix it?

**Edit:** Here is the snippet that the course provided for reading the input. I hadn't used `sys.stdin` before this week.

```
import sys

input = sys.stdin.read()
tokens = input.split()
a = int(tokens[0])
b = int(tokens[1])

print(a + b)
```

(they chose to use the input keyword as a variable, not me!)

Comment: Why do you use `ctrl + D` to end the input?

Comment: I just added the python snippet the TAs provided to collect the input - I don't know why they chose that over a typical `input()` that would end itself when you hit enter.

Comment: Could you post the full code, please?

Comment: @Anwarvic: `Ctrl-D` is the standard chord to end stdin in a terminal. Pretty sure the output is coming from the terminal or shell itself, not from Python. If you add `print(repr(input))` you'd see if the EOF actually appeared in what Python received, or was just echoed as you typed.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, that's a good point

Comment: I added the full snippet. Oddly, when I add `print(input)`, there is no extra D.

Comment: I'd test using a file or <<tag shell feature.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it is old keyboard echo (where did the line feed go?)  Try feeding shell input using something like:

```
command-and-args <<!EOF
input lines
!EOF
```